# Why invoking ElementTree.parse function twice in one script will get an exception?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I need to process two xml files in one script.
So, I wrote some codes like below:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
ET.parse('../wiki.xml', parser=parser)
ET.parse('../tutorial.xml', parser=parser)
```

However, the second call `parse` got an exception.

```
cElementTree.ParseError: parsing finished
```

But, I ensure that both xml files have no inner problems, because when I changed the order the second invoke always got an exception and if I reserved one there was no problem.

So, why invoking ElementTree.parse function twice in one script will get an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're supposed to create new parser for each tree. Because parser holds parsed state inside, it can't be used to parse another tree.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

parser1 = ET.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
ET.parse('../wiki.xml', parser=parser1)
parser2 = ET.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
ET.parse('../tutorial.xml', parser=parser2)
```

Comment: This solution is right, thanks! However, whether existing one method can clear the parser's state?

Comment: As from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xmlparser-objects) I don't see one. You can experiment with `close()` method, but I'm not sure it'll do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could also delete each tree before constructing the next one:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
...
for xml_file in xml_files:
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    analyze_one_file(root)
    del root
    del tree
```